# onload event event javascript not responding

Tags: javascript

Javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function react() {
     document.getElementById("img").src = second.jpg
  }
</script>
```

Html Page:

```
<div style="width:170px;height:160px;border:2px solid blue">
 <img src="first.jpg" style="width:inherit;height:inherit" id="img" onload="setTimeout('react()', 15000)"/>
</div>
```

Please the The image in the does not change as it is meant to change from first.jpg to second.jpg in 15000 milliseconds as set by the setTimeout() function

Comment: You need to learn how to debug JavaScript. There is a glaring error that should produce some sort of output in the error console

Answer (score 1):

`second.jpg` means "The `jpg` property of the `second` object" (which is hasn't been mentioned before so it will throw a reference error).

You need to use a string literal: `"second.jpg"`.

Comment: You can use firebug in firefox browser to debug

Answer (score 1):

second.jpg should be in quotes,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function react() {
  document.getElementById("img").src = 'second.jpg';
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The string value must be between quotes. Also, you should ad `onload` event in `<body>` tag.

> document.getElementById("img").src = 'second.jpg';

Answer (score 1):

second.jpg should be quoted and the `setTimeout` accepts a function reference:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function react() {
     document.getElementById("img").src = "second.jpg"
  }
</script>

<div style="width:170px;height:160px;border:2px solid blue">
 <img src="first.jpg" style="width:inherit;height:inherit" id="img" onload="setTimeout(react, 15000);"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The IMG tag does nopt support the onload attribute. Move it to the body tag:

```
<body onload="setTimeout('react()', 15000)">
  <div style="width:170px;height:160px;border:2px solid blue">
   <img src="first.jpg" style="width:inherit;height:inherit" id="img" />
  </div>
</body>
```

Also, enclose second.jpg in your react function in quotes.

Comment: Definitely `img` "supports" `onload`, and that's actually which makes this your code snippet brilliant here. Currently OP's code creates an infinite loop, it reloads the image every 15th sec.